# System Call in Rails returns 'No such file or directory'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to execute shell commands in rails using the following:

```
result = `which wkhtmltoimage-proxy`
```

but I always get back:

```
No such file or directory - which wkhtmltoimage-proxy
```

If I just type the command in my shell, everything works but not in the rails environment.

Doesn't matter which commands I try, none of the work.

Do I need to configure anything in rails?

Comment: Sounds like you have an empty `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Do I need to configure this in rails?  PATH variable in my shell is fine.

Comment: If I try it in the Rails console, it works.  But it doesn't work in my application.  So how would I go about fixing this problem?

Comment: I figured it out.  I am using an IDE tool and didn't set the environment variables correctly.  Anyways, the problem is solved now.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I am using an IDE tool and didn't set the environment variables correctly. Anyways, the problem is solved now. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Then you should [accept your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask). In this case you question won't be considered unanswered anymore.

Comment: I will as soon as stackoverflow allows me to in 21 hours

Answer (score 0):

Think of the system ticks (`) as executing in your rails directory (i.e. 'myapp')

So, if you're expecting to run this command in another directory, such as your home folder, you'll have to specify that

```
result = `cd ~ && which wkhtmltoimage-proxy`
```

Comment: I don't think this is my problem because even if I do \`ls\`, I still get "No such file or directory - ls".  It just seems to not recognize any shell commands.

Comment: try running in rails console, both with and without the 'cd ~'

Comment: Works in Rails console regardless of directory, but not in my application :(  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If this is on Windows

> This is spec. Ruby doesn't execute any child process in such case on
>   Windows, so, ruby cannot set any status to $?.

[bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1690](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/1690)